# es6 : covert object to array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have records :

```
 let a =  [{
            "resource" : "user",

            "permissions" : [ 
                "add", 
                "list", 
                "verify", 
                "add-credit", 
                "deactive", 
                "trash", 
                "edit", 
                "impersonate", 
                "active"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "resource" : "company",

            "permissions" : [ 
                "list", 
                "verify", 
                "pending", 
                "reject"
            ]
        }];
```

I want to convert it to :

```
{"user":[ 
                "add", 
                "list", 
                "verify", 
                "add-credit", 
                "deactive", 
                "trash", 
                "edit", 
                "impersonate", 
                "active"
         ], 
        "company" : [ 
                "list", 
                "verify", 
                "pending", 
                "reject"
            ]
     };
```

This can be done via the custom function to foreach and store the result to another variable.

What I want is to do it with `map`, `filter`, or any new feature of javascript in es6.

I have tried using `map`.

```
 a.map(function (res){return res.resource})
```

Comment: Please share your attempt as well.

Comment: *So what I **want***, want means requirement. SO is for problem statement

Comment: I edit my question. :) thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `reduce`

```
var output = a.reduce( ( acc, c ) => {
  acc[ c.resource ] = c.permissions;
  return acc; //return accumulator
} ,{}) // initialize accumulator to {}
```

**Explanation**

- Use `reduce` to *iterate and initialize* the *accumulator* `acc` as *empty object* `{}`.
- For each item `c` in the array `a`

  - Assign `c.resource` value (*user* and *company*) as property to `acc` (accumulator) and value of that property being `c.permissions`
  - `return` the *accumulator* `acc`.

Comment: @Rajesh Added some explanation, hope it is useful. I had already given some comments earlier as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although this has been answered by using `reduce` but this is just to clarify that it can be done this way which is much more understanding if you do not understand how `reduce` works or if you do not want to use `reduce`

```js
let a =  [{
            "resource" : "user",

            "permissions" : [ 
                "add", 
                "list", 
                "verify", 
                "add-credit", 
                "deactive", 
                "trash", 
                "edit", 
                "impersonate", 
                "active"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "resource" : "company",

            "permissions" : [ 
                "list", 
                "verify", 
                "pending", 
                "reject"
            ]
        }];
        
var res = {};
a.forEach((obj)=>{
  res[obj.resource] = obj.permissions;
});
console.log(res);
```